# NCalc expression evaluation error for custom function

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, expression, ncalc

I have an expression which has all calls to all custom functions.

```
IIF(FVAL(DES_CODE)=1039 OR FVAL(DES_CODE)=1040 OR FVAL(DES_CODE)=1034,0,TBLEVA(PTAX, FVAL(HOPO_GRS)))
```

When trying to evaluate this expression the `NCalc` engine is producing an error. I'm not able to figure out why. All function declared in the expression has been handled in the `EvalFunction` event of the expression. Then why is this error arising?

```
mismatched input 'OR' expecting ')' at line 1:24 missing EOF at 'OR' at line 1:47
```

**CODE -**

This is where I'm initializing the expression engine.

```
Dim exp As New Expression(vbCode, EvaluateOptions.IgnoreCase)
AddHandler exp.EvaluateParameter, AddressOf EvalParameters
AddHandler exp.EvaluateFunction, AddressOf EvalFunction
xReturn = Convert.ToDecimal(exp.Evaluate())
```

These are the events for the expression.

```
Public Sub EvalFunction(ByVal name As String, ByVal args As FunctionArgs)
    Select Case name.ToUpper.Trim
        Case "FVAL"
            Dim xobj = args.EvaluateParameters()
            args.Result = fc.Fval(xobj(0))
        Case "ORIGINALVAL"
            Dim xobj = args.EvaluateParameters()
            args.Result = fc.ORIGINALVAL(xobj(0))
        Case "IIF"
            Dim xobj = args.EvaluateParameters()
            args.Result = fc.IIF(xobj(0), xobj(1), xobj(2))
        Case "LOANDEDUCT"
            Dim xobj = args.EvaluateParameters()
            args.Result = fc.LOANDEDUCT(xobj(0))
        Case "TBLEVA"
            Dim xobj = args.EvaluateParameters()
            args.Result = fc.TBLEVA(xobj(0), xobj(1))
        Case "PERIODMONTH"
            args.Result = fc.PERIODMONTH()
        Case "PERIODSTART"
            args.Result = fc.PERIODSTART()
        Case "AGE"
            Dim xobj = args.EvaluateParameters()
            args.Result = fc.Age(xobj(0))
        Case "INT"
            Dim xobj = args.EvaluateParameters()
            args.Result = fc.Age(xobj(0))
    End Select
End Sub
Public Sub EvalParameters(ByVal name As String, ByVal args As ParameterArgs)
    args.Result = name
End Sub
```

Comment: The expression is not enough. You should show also your code.

Comment: I've added code. But that doesn't help, because the expression is not being parsed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `OR`s with `||` or `or`(lowercase)

```
IIF(FVAL(DES_CODE)=1039 || FVAL(DES_CODE)=1040 || FVAL(DES_CODE)=1034,0,TBLEVA(PTAX, FVAL(HOPO_GRS)))
```

Comment: But why not `OR`. I mean its officially supported.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta `||` or `or`(lowercase) is allowed

Comment: Brilliant. I didn't know that these were case sensitive. But then `EvaluateOptions.IgnoreCase` has no effect right?